# Any idea how to convert and Octal number to a decimal with recursion?

Tags: c++, recursion

I want to convert an octal number to a decimal number using recursion.
So far i can write the correct number but backwards, i still need to swap the order, how can i do this? 
My code (giving the backwards number):

```
void decimalToOctal(int num) {
   int  total = 0;
   if (num > 0)
   {
       total = num % 8;
       num /= 8;
       cout << total;
       decimalToOctal(num);
   }
}
```

Imagine if the correct decimal number was 234, this code is giving 432.

Comment: @Tuffwer - that's the point. This is the usual approach for picking off digits.

Comment: @Tuffwer There is no rounding involved in int by int divisions.

Comment: @Tuffwer: Integer division is correct here—the algorithm is discarding the last octal digit, or equivalently the last three binary digits.

Comment: Yep totally makes sense, whelp going to delete that comment then.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just move the printout to after the recursion, like this

```
void decimalToOctal(int num) {
   int  total = 0;
   if (num > 0)
   {
      total = num % 8;
      num /= 8;
      decimalToOctal(num);
      cout << total;
   }
}
```

Comment: That didn't work.. If i pass num=564 for example, it should be 372 the correct number but its giving 1064 :s

Comment: Never mind. You are right. Thanks! was so simple ahah thank you

Comment: You can also make it half the length and lose the local var by making `{decimalToOctal(num / 8); cout << num % 8;}` the `if` block.

Comment: Note: prints nothing if `num < 0`.

Comment: @chux -- That is true, to solve for zero you would need to wrap the recursive call in an if statement, and while at it you may also want to consider how you want to deal with negative number in the same wrapper.